# Sum elements in a list of lists and find maximum in Python

Tags: python, list, sum, max

I don't know how to do this:
I have a `list` of `list`s defined like this:

```
list=[[day,type,expense],[...]];
```

day and expense are `int`, type is `string`

I need to find the max expense by day. An example:

```
list=[[1,'food',15],[4,'rent', 50],[1,'other',60],[8,'bills',40]]
```

I need to sum the elements that have the same day and find the day with the highest expenses.

The result should be:

```
day:1, total expenses:75
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [[1, 'food', 15], [4,'rent', 50], [1, 'other', 60], [8, 'bills', 40]]
hash = {}
for item in list:
    if item[0] not in hash.keys():
        hash[item[0]] = item[2]
    else:
        hash[item[0]] += item[2]

for (k, v) in hash:
    # print key: value
```

or if you just want the most expensive day.

```
for (k, v) in hash:
    if (v == max(hash.values()):
        #print k: v
```

Comment: Since i'm a beginner in python, i find this answer to my understanding. Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

Isn't a defaultdict just as easy?

```
import pprint
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter

l = [[1, 'food', 15], [4, 'rent', 50], [1, 'other', 60], [8, 'bills', 40]]
d = defaultdict(int)
for item in l:
    d[item[0]] += item[2]
pprint.pprint(dict(d))
print max(d.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Result:

```
{1: 75, 4: 50, 8: 40}
(1, 75)
```

Comment: `max(d.iteritems(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))`

Comment: Thanks, missed the final step.

Answer (score 2):

```
data=[[1,'food',15],[4,'rent', 50],[1,'other',60],[8,'bills',40]]

# put same days together
data.sort()


# aggregate the days
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

grouped = groupby(data, key=itemgetter(0))


# sum values by day
summed = ((day, sum(val for (_,_,val) in day_group))
          for day, day_group in grouped)


# get the max
print max(summed, key=itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I like `groupby` too, but if the data is unsorted I think a `defaultdict` is more natural. Random suggestions: I'd use an `itemgetter` key function for the `sort` too so as to avoid doing extra comparisons. Also, if you're going to use `itemgetter` for the `key` functions (I realize those have to be functions), why not also use it for the summing (even though you don't have to use a function there)? `valgetter = itemgetter(2)` then a generator expression or `map` with `valgetter` -- `sum(map(valgetter, day_group))`.